# Is there a first-order formulation of CP-violating QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-chromodynamics

In QCD without a CP violating $\theta$ term, (I believe) we can express the gauge kinetic Lagrangian in a first-order form with the field strength $F_{\mu\nu}$ taken to be Lagrange multipliers.  Up to signs and constant coefficients:

$$
\mathcal L = \mathrm{Tr} \left[ F^{\mu\nu} (\partial_\mu G_{\nu} + ig \, G_\nu G_\mu) - \tfrac14 F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu} \right]
$$

Can the same thing be done when a CP-violating term

$$
\frac{\theta}{32\pi^2} \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} F^{\mu\nu} F^{\rho\sigma}
$$

is included?